# center the text in position 0, code problem xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android, spinner, gravity

I looked everywhere, but for the moment works.

here is my code:

```
     <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/departement"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                     />


      Spinner departement = (Spinner)sender;
      ((TextView)departement.GetChildAt(0)).SetForegroundGravity(GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal);
      ((TextView)departement.GetChildAt(0)).SetTextColor(Color.White);
```

the color works, but the center position does not. do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a new xml to define the content of that item in Spinner.

And cusotmize the style in that xml .

##### Item.xml

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"    //center
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>   //Textcolor
```

##### Set in Adapter

```cs
ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,Resource.Layout.Item,items);
departement.Adapter = adapter;
```

Comment: @michael Have you solved the problem ?